# Enter key for Route another page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a input for searchbox. I must make like; Write my words fors search then after i press enter it must need go another page with input value. So i can access that value with query string. So how can i route another page with value of input after i press enter ? Thank you for help! I Just add That codes for catch enter press.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event) => {
      if (event.code === "Enter" || event.code === "NumpadEnter") {
        alert("Enter key was pressed. Run your function.");
        event.preventDefault();
         
         
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to set an event listener, using `onKeyDown` event handler will also do. Enter key has a code of `13`, so we just have to detect that.

Keep your value in a state (here, `myValue`), detect that you've pressed Enter key (here, using `keyPressHandler` method), and finally, pass the parameter to your route.

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  let history = useHistory();

  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setMyValue(value);
  };

  const keyPressHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      // alert("You pressed enter!");
      history.push("/process/" + myValue);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={myValue} onKeyDown={keyPressHandler} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**UPDATE:**
According to MDN Web Docs, `e.which` is non-standard [[Source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which) and `e.keyCode` is deprecated [[Source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), so you should be using `e.key` instead like:

```
  const keyPressHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.key=== 'Enter') {
      // alert("You pressed enter!");
      history.push("/process/" + myValue);
    }
  };
```

[Working CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-pike-smv10?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you so much! Its exactly what i want!